# Se puede comprobar si una función retorna algún valor? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes compañeros, lo que estoy intentando hacer es comprobar si una función anónima pasada como parámetro a otra función de JS retorna valor sin tener que ejecutarla previamente para comprobar el valor retornado sea != a undefined

```
miFuncion("param1", ()=>{
   //logica
   //return ....
})

function miFuncion(param1, funcionAnonima){
  //comprobar acá si "funcionAnonima" retorna un valor o undefined
}
```

La razón es porque me armé una pequeña librería para escribir código HTML desde javascript, la cual estoy usando y me funciona bien, y lo que necesito es tirar una excepción en el caso de que el segundo parámetro sea una función pero no retorne valor alguno. 
Comparto el repo de la librería en github [enlace](https://github.com/gianlucafiore/VanillaJsEloquent)

De todos modos explico rápidamente como funcionaría:
por ejemplo para crear un "DIV"

```
//Esta es la funcion declarada en la libreria
const DIV = (atributes,innerHTML)=> //el innerHTML va a ser la función anonima
{
    //Acá es donde quiero tirar una excepción en caso de que innerHTML no retorne valores
    let elm = document.createElement("div"); 
    return defaultFunction(atributes,innerHTML,elm).outerHTML
    //defaultFunction es simplemente una función que agrega los atributos
    //y retorna el elemento HTML para ser escrito en el DOM
}


//Esto es implementando la librería en el proyecto

document.getElementById("body").innerHTML =
DIV({class:"row"}, ()=>
    DIV({class:"col"},()=>
      INPUT({type:"text", id="text", placeholder:"any text"})
    )+
    DIV({class:"col"},()=>
      INPUT({type:"number", placeholder:"any number"})
    )+
    DIV({class:"col"},()=>
      BUTTON({type:"button", class:"btn btn-submit"}, ()=> "Concatenate")
    )+
  )
```

El problema surge en si se me olvida escribir el returnt dentro de las llaves después del arrow function

```
()=>{}
```

En casos en los que el innerHTML deba hacer validaciones o ejecuciones extras, y retornar un valor procesado ahí, me queda el innerHTML como "undefined", ya que la función no devolvio ningun valor

Comment: Si explicaras la razon por la que quieres esto, podria ayudarte. Edita tu pregunta y agrega la razon.

Comment: @Einer Editado, gracias

Comment: @GianlucaFiore que atributos pones aqui  = (atributes, innerHTML, elm)

Comment: en "attributes" va un objeto js, por ejemplo {class:"col"}...
En "innerHTML" una función que retorna texto plano o más texto html para crear hijos de los elementos, y en "elm" va el elemento virgen creado recientemente, dentro de esa función se agregan los atributos al html, se valida que el inner sea una función que retorna un string, pero necesito que ese error se pueda controlar antes para poder arrojar excepciones más explícitas

Answer (score 1):

Hola prueba con esto a ver si obtienes el resultado que quieres

```
//Esta es la funcion declarada en la libreria
const DIV = (atributes,innerHTML)=> //el innerHTML va a ser la función anonima
{
    if (innerHTML!=undefined){
        let elm = document.createElement("div"); 
        return defaultFunction(atributes,innerHTML,elm).outerHTML
    }
}

//Esto es implementando la librería en el proyecto

document.getElementById("body").innerHTML =
DIV({class:"row"}, ()=>
    DIV({class:"col"},()=>
      INPUT({type:"text", id="text", placeholder:"any text"})
    )+
    DIV({class:"col"},()=>
      INPUT({type:"number", placeholder:"any number"})
    )+
    DIV({class:"col"},()=>
      BUTTON({type:"button", class:"btn btn-submit"}, ()=> "Concatenate")
    )+
  )
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero hacer eso implica ejecutar la función, además de que no se está almacenando el dato en ninguna variable

Comment: lamento que te pueda ayudar, en todo caso si quieres el dato en una variable solo tienes que declararla y almacenar el dato 'let valorFuncionAnonima=funcionAnonima();'

Comment: He editado la respuesta adaptandola al codigo que has añadido, espero que te ayude

Comment: Sí, esa respuesta se acerca más a lo que preciso, ya la tenía en cuenta en caso de no hallar solución alternativa, la idea era no tener que repetir el "if" con la ejecución del innerHTML en cada función creadora de elementos HTML ya que de eso se encargaba una sola vez la "defaultFunction" y se repite su uso igual en todas las funciones para crear cada tipo de etiqueta (div, form, input, button, etc..), la "defaultFunction" tendria que pasar a llamarse "addAttributes" ya que solo sería para añadir atributos.gracias por el aguante!

Comment: Bueno, sigue investigando y probando, si hay alguna solucion mas factible ya la encontraras, animo.